# Why is my declared variable before the include statement not working in my include file

Tags: php, variables, include

Need help to use a variable in my include file.

This is my file which I declare variables and include a file:- (it is 2 sub directories down)

```
<?php
$year = "2020";
$one = "2020/test/janb1.csv";
include 'https://test.com/index.php';
?>
```

This is a snippet of my index.php file

```
<?php
$rows = file("2020/test/janb1.csv");
       ........................
```

Now I want to use $one instead of "2020/test/janb1.csv"

Itried

```
$rows = file(".$one.");
echo $rows = file(".$one.");
```

but it's not working

Comment: Periods are for the outside of the quotes. You don't need quotes if you're just passing in the variable.

Comment: You are including by HTTP URL, which makes a completely separate HTTP request that shares none of the context of the including file. This is almost certainly a mistake (especially since you talk about directories, which aren't a thing in HTTP requests). In fact, I urge you to [disable this feature in php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) because it's a serious security risk. It should be off by default, actually.

Comment: To follow up Peter's comment: assuming that `index.php` is on the same server as the  script you're showing us, you can probably just write `include "index.php";` instead. (Or you might need to include a path, if it's not in the same directory as you mentioned - e.g. `include "path/to/index.php";`)

Comment: I had a type error the index file was actually in a sub folder `include 'https://test.com/test/index.php;`
Tried all suggestion and could only getting it to work with
`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/index.php");`